# Convolutional NN for text input in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a [text classification model](http://d3kbpzbmcynnmx.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Screen-Shot-2015-11-06-at-12.05.40-PM.png) using a CNN. As far as I know, for text data, we should use 1d Convolutions. I saw an example in pytorch using Conv2d but I want to know how can I apply Conv1d for text? Or, it is actually not possible?

Here is my model scenario:

```
Number of in-channels: 1, Number of out-channels: 128 
Kernel size : 3 (only want to consider trigrams)
Batch size : 16
```

So, I will provide tensors of shape, <16, 1, 28, 300> where 28 is the length of a sentence. I want to use Conv1d which will give me 128 feature maps of length 26 (as I am considering trigrams).

I am not sure, how to define nn.Conv1d() for this setting. I can use Conv2d but want to know is it possible to achieve the same using Conv1d?

Comment: Where's the 300 coming from?

Comment: 300 is the embedding dimension.

Comment: to clarify Wasi's answer: nn.Conv1d(300, 128, 2). i/p = 28 words of 300 dimensions each in batches of 16 given in the format <16,300,28>; o/p = 26 words of 128 dimensions each in batches of 16 obtained in the format: <16,128,26>. This format is for PyTorch. The format may vary slightly from FW to FW

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This [example](https://gist.github.com/spro/c87cc706625b8a54e604fb1024106556) of Conv1d and Pool1d layers into an RNN resolved my issue.

So, I need to consider the embedding dimension as the number of in-channels while using `nn.Conv1d` as follows.

```
m = nn.Conv1d(200, 10, 2) # in-channels = 200, out-channels = 10
input = Variable(torch.randn(10, 200, 5)) # 200 = embedding dim, 5 = seq length
feature_maps = m(input)
print(feature_maps.size()) # feature_maps size = 10,10,4
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution! I've been trying to implement the same net and only found examples using 2D convolution. This example is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't work with text data, the input tensor in its current form would only work using conv2d. One possible way to use conv1d would be to concatenate the embeddings in a tensor of shape e.g. <16,1,28*300>. You can reshape the input with `view` In pytorch.